# Classic main-menu and ribbon at the same time?

Tags: menu, actions, ribbon

I recently added 'Ribbons' to my application(for experts, as browser-app) which look and work the same way as you know from 'Windows-8' or MS-Word; eg. showing tabs, quick-launch buttons and a expand/collapse toggle.

Should I remove now my classic top-bar main-menu or leave it optionally to the user?  I guess I should leave both visible and combine both concepts. For instance, the main-menu always shows all actions, whilst the Ribbons only show the more used actions, right?

Thank you!

appendix:

This is how it looks when all toolbars  and menus are shown:

[image]

As far I understood, Ribbons have been developed to discover new functions in MicroSoft products and are somehow no real replacement for a classic main-menu. I also understand that Ribbons work fine for showing the more frequent used actions, and enable customization of these.

You can see in the picture that the main-menu, the Ribbon and the local action-toolbar(file browser) might overwhelm the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could **hide the classic menu and toggle its display between hidden and shown when the alt key is pressed** (just like Microsoft does).

**Screen real-estate is important**. If the classic menu would be used less, then removing it or hiding is a valid decision. You should always work towards [reducing the cognitive (visual) load](http://stc-access.org/wp-content/uploads/tracy_measuring_cognitive_load.pdf) on the application itself. The more options you place on the screen, the harder it is to find something asap.

*Since the Ribbon menu is just like MS-Word and windows 8, your users would be familiar with the press alt to display classic menu feature. Its a popular convention among windows OS users* You could always list this feature in the information/help section.

**With Alt function, you could add shortcut keys to menus**. Keyboard users would love you for that. Personally, I find keyboard shortcuts a lot faster to work with than mouse/touch interactions.

Comment: yeah, I guessed so. Thank you. I am considering to accept it soon, still waiting for others :-)

Comment: I agree that the <kbd>alt</kbd> toggle is the best idea, but I think you're overestimating how many users know about it. Even I as a poweruser often forgot about it (before switching away from Microsoft Office entirely).